# Brushes have no effect

Tags: sculpting

When I change to sculpt mode no brush seems to work and I have no conclusion why this is the case. Maybe It is because of my ATI 6670 Graphic Card?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Try subdividing your mesh. The sculpt tool only can interact with vertices you already have. Alternatively, you can try enabling `Dyntopo` in the viewport tool shelf.